# Can a bare insulated wire from inside to outside defeat Faraday cage?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-radiation

So I seem to have boosted the WiFi signal inside my enclosed metal room/box by passing an unconnected wire underneath a crack in the door... is this possible or am I imagining it?

My room has metal throughout all four walls and ceiling plus a sheet of metal on one side of the door, The only non metal openings are via a window on the opposite side from the on premises WiFi signal and a minimal crack under the door [also presumably there is not much metal in the floor] where I usually receive a week signal (tested by watching signal strength as I move the laptop WRT the base of the door). Tonight on a whim placed one end of an unconnected audio cable outside the room and fed the other end under the door to inside the room - Can't exactly explain my reasoning except it being something to do with one end of the wire being a receiving antenna and the other end of same wire being a transmitting antenna... Long story short I currently have an almost full signal compared to other nights where it would be dropping in and out.

My question is would this simple trick be responsible and if so whats the physics behind it? or is the unusually good signal tonight more likely due to unknown external factor (or my imagination)?

*PS. I have a proper WiFi extender coming in the mail which I will be positioning outside the window as a more robust solution - this little experiment was just for a short term fix.*

Comment: Two people have voted to close without any comment... care to elaborate?